# base64_decode return null when trying to upload image

Tags: java, php, base64, decode

I am trying to upload an image to server but `base64_decode` always returns null
i read a lot of different cases from SO but nothing works.
here is my java code before i make my http request:

```
      ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            // Must compress the Image to reduce image size to make upload easy
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 50, stream); 
            byte[] byte_arr = stream.toByteArray();
            // Encode Image to String
            encodedString = Base64.encodeToString(byte_arr,Base64.NO_WRAP);
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_IMAGE, encodedString));
           ...and the http request
```

php code:

```
                     $base=$_REQUEST['image'];
                          //$response["base"] = $base;
                       $binary=base64_decode($base,TRUE);
                          $response["binary"] = $binary;
                         header('Content-Type: bitmap; charset=utf-8'); 
                         $imagepath='the path of the image';
                            $file = fopen($imagepath, 'w');
                            fwrite($file, $binary);
                            fclose($file);
```

i also tried  `$file = fopen($imagepath, 'wb');` still `$binary` is always return with `null`;
somebody can please help me understand what is the problem?

also i checked `$base` and it looks ok, i also tried to remove `\n` or `\\` but nothing helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so i figure it out:
1. the path that you need to save the image must be relative to the web service (php code in my case) in the server which also mean you have to save the image at the same server.
2. file_put_contents is a lot easyier to use and replace the fopen, fwrite and fclose together and save you trubble. 
i hope it will help you guys